# install the same extension twice(to work seperatly)

Tags: magento2, module, custom-shipping-method

I installed this extension:
https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-custom-shipping
in order to have a custom shipping method in my magento 2 store and it works fine.

I neet to have another shipping method with fixed price so I would like to install this extension again...

I guess I should change some files but I don't know exactly which files to edit and where..

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you not use the Flat Shipping method for this?

Comment: I am already using it for something else, but now when I checked it out I can use the table rates for this "something else" and define my own rules for it and for my custom shipping use the flat shipping. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the module multiple times as that would involve duplicating a lot of code. You would basically need to make changes in every single file in the codebase, replacing MagePsycho\Customshipping with something else, let's say MagePsycho\Customshipping2 and references to magepsycho in all of the non-XML files.

Consider using Magento native table rates http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html

Or, one of these modules allowing you to generate custom shipping carriers form the Admin:

- https://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-shipping-suite.html
- https://amasty.com/shipping-table-rates-for-magento-2.html